# What is the right way to tag a question about a new game when I cannot create a tag yet?

Tags: discussion

I just started on gaming.stackexchange and I wanted to post a question about Particle Fleet Emergence, however there isn't a tag for it yet. I know someone with more rep could simply create a tag, but how do I handle this issue if I cannot create the tag myself. Is there a generic tag I should use or something?

Comment: In short; tag it with the game's system (pc, 3ds, ps4, etc...) and make clear the exact name of the game somewhere in the question title/body, and before long a user with enough reputation will create the tag.